# Linking to PNG file beginning with hash symbol

Tags: html, image, png

I have two image files in my directory. One is called `abc1.png` and the other is called `#abc1.png`.

When I do

`<img src="abc1.png" alt="Figure">`

in my HTML file, it works fine. But when I do

`<img src="#abc1.png" alt="Figure">`,

the image doesn't show up. Why is it?

Comment: i'm not sure if it applies to html, but i don't think you can have a symbol such as # as the beginning of a valid file url

Comment: I recommend a different naming scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML the # sign is a reference to a named anchor in the document.  You are telling the browser to look for that.  Instead, use the URI-encoded version of #:

```
<img src="%23abc1.png" alt="Figure">
```

Depending on your setup, you may have to double-encode it.

Comment: I should be added that this (to have a filename starting with  `#`) is quite unusual and, while not illegal, it can be confusing and lead to problems.